# Preprocessor definition works in Visual Studio and doesn't work in Qt-creator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qmake, c-preprocessor

**.pro file:**

```
DEFINES += MY_HEADER=\"test.h\"
```

**cpp file:**

```
#include MY_HEADER
```

In Qt-Creator compilation failed with error:

> error C2006: '#include' : expected a filename, found 'identifier'

Compiler command line seems to be correct:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Debug
>       cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- /E -Zi -MDd /E -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DMY_HEADER="test.h" -DLLL=3 -DQT_DLL -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"c:\Qt\4.7.4\include\QtCore" -I"c:\Qt\4.7.4\include" -I"c:\Qt\4.7.4\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"..\testdefine" -I"." -I"c:\Qt\4.7.4\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Ekimov-A\AppData\Local\Temp\nm9C17.tmp

When the  project is imported to Visual studio with Qt-addin this code compiled without any problems.

Comment: I tried
    MY_HEADER=test.h and 'MY_HEADER="test.h"' with the same results.

Comment: For first variant command line contains -DMY_HEADER=test.h, for second -DMY_HEADER="test.h".

Comment: If i define something like DEFINES += LLL=3, int a = LLL; it works fine everywere.

Answer (score 2):

It's seems to be a qmake bug(feature?). Possible workarounds:

```
DEFINES += 'MY_HEADER=\\\"test.h\\\"'
```

or

```
DEFINES += MY_HEADER=\\\"test.h\\\"
```